# How to remove target for unit tests in Xcode5?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode5

I'v just upgraded to Xcode5, and my unit tests with OCUnit (SenTestingKit.framework) stopped to work. I'v tried various solutions but none of them helped, so I'v decided to remove the target for tests and add a new target "Cocoa Unit Testing Bundle" with XCTest. I know I could ask Xcode to convert existing one, but I would like to make a clean remove and add a fresh one. However, I can't find how to remove the target. Any ideas, where the button is hidden :) ?

Comment: [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529783/remove-unit-testing-from-xcode-5-project check this link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried turning it off and on again? :)

Just right-click (command-click) the target:

[image]

Or select the target and hit the `Delete` (Del) key.

Comment: Thanks. The pane was closed by default, and I haven't noticed show/hide pane arrow button :)

Comment: But this did not delete source files which created for Unit testing..any idea ?

Comment: Yes, delete those as well. Deleting a target doesn't and shouldn't delete any files.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, delete unit test folder or any other target you have in your xcode project.
After that , go to your project info section. [You fill find in the top file named with your given project name]
In the info tab, you will see targets you have , right click on the target you want to delete and it will be completely removed .