# Remove unit testing from Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

When I created my iOS project in Xcode 5 I clicked the option to add testing to the project.  Is it possible to remove all that testing stuff, just as though I hadn't clicked the option to begin with?

Comment: I strongly suggest you rethink this.

Comment: In my case, I had an empty Objective-C test set. I wanted to remove it, so I could add a new Swift-based test set. The OP didn't say they weren't going to have tests - they just wanted to remove the ones that were there - and I'm grateful for the question.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I suggest to **make test** in your project.

But in any case, you might to leave there the target.

Otherwise, if you want delete at any cost, you have just to **click on your project settings** and click on this icon:

[image]

You will see your **targets** and you will can delete the **test target**. At this point you might want **delete the test classes** too: on the folder hierarchy, select these and just press backspace, confirming the deletion.

Answer (score 64):

## Xcode 7+

Click your project name in the Project Navigator. Then select your Tests target. Click the minus (-) button at the bottom to delete it. (Select everywhere in red in the image below.)

[image]

As mentioned in a comment earlier, it is a good idea to do Unit Testing (and UI testing) in your projects. So, if you want to add them back in then just click the plus (+) button.

**See also**

- [How to do a Unit Test in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31570612/3681880)
- [Xcode UI Test example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600777/xcode-ui-test-example)