# Disable Test target in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, unit-testing, testing, target

I have 2 targets in my Xcode project, 1 app target and 1 test target.
Since my project has become rather large to compile I want to disable the test target so it doesn't need to compile my Swift files twice for both targets.

Any idea how to disable (not remove) my test target from building?

Comment: Look here: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324163/xcode-how-to-delete-target-in-xcode-6-1 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529783/remove-unit-testing-from-xcode-5-project

Comment: not removing, but disabling

Comment: Just select the target you want to build... It will not compile the other one

Answer (score 18):

There is a `disable` option if you right-click on the target, in the test targets view:

[image: Disable tests target]